# How do I make a cleaner JS color flipper without muddying the DOM?

Tags: javascript, css

I built a random color flipper with setInterval and Math.random.

Here's the console warning from my current approach:

"Expected color but found ‘#3acf4’.  Error in parsing value for ‘color’.  Declaration dropped."

I think my logic may be backwards somewhere.

Does anyone perhaps know how I can make this JS a bit more terse and clear the warning?

Please and thanks!

```js
// grabbing elements
const wrap = document.querySelector('.page-wrap');
const infinite = document.querySelector('.infinite-button');
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset-button');
let randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
let interval;

// starting color flip
infinite.addEventListener('click', colorRandomizer);

// reset color flip
reset.addEventListener('click', colorStopper);

// timing color flips 
function colorRandomizer() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    colorMetrics();
  }, 300);
}

// stopping color flips
function colorStopper() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  wrap.style.backgroundColor = '';
}

// refreshing random colors
function inifiniteColor() {
  if (randomColor != '') {
    randomColor = '';
  } else if (randomColor == '') {
    randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  }
  return randomColor;
}

// monkey around with the dom
function colorMetrics() {
  if (wrap.style.backgroundColor == '') {
    wrap.style.backgroundColor = inifiniteColor();
  } else if (wrap.style.backgroundColor == '#randomColor') {
    wrap.style.backgroundColor = inifiniteColor();
  } else {
    wrap.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}
```

```css
.page-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.infinite-button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid dimGrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.infinite-button:hover {
  color: yellowGreen;
  background: dimGrey;
  border-color: yellowGreen;
}

.infinite-dood {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

.reset-button {
  color: indianRed;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid indianRed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.reset-button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: indianRed;
  border-color: darkRed;
}

.reset-dood {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <button class="infinite-button">
    <p class="infinite-dood">
      &#8734;
    </p>
  </button>
  <button class="reset-button">
    <p class="reset-dood">
      X
    </p>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The color produced is only 5 characters and colors are required to be 6 characters. Zero-pad the number. You don't need the initial value of `randomColor`, because you don't need it to be a global variable in the first place. Just pass the value into the `inifiniteColor` function.

Comment: Additionally you need to `clearInterval(interval)` every time the infinite button is clicked since people can press that over and over, creating additional intervals

Answer (score 2):

Like @Heretic Monkey said... *"The color produced is only 5 characters and colors are required to be 6 characters."*

I played your CodePen for many minutes and that error didn't show... But anyway, you could try this:

```
function inifiniteColor() {
  if (randomColor != '') {
    randomColor = '';
  } else if (randomColor == '') {
    randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

    // If randomColor length is not 7 (# + 6 hex), complete with zeros
    if(randomColor.length<7){
      randomColor = randomColor + "0".repeat(7-randomColor.length)
    }
  }
  return randomColor;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// grabbing elements
const wrap = document.querySelector('.page-wrap');
const infinite = document.querySelector('.infinite-button');
const reset = document.querySelector('.reset-button');
let interval;

// starting color flip
infinite.addEventListener('click', () => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    wrap.style.backgroundColor =
      ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
  }, 300);
});

// reset color flip
reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  wrap.style.backgroundColor = '';
});
```

```css
.page-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.infinite-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid dimGrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.infinite-button:hover {
  color: yellowGreen;
  background: dimGrey;
  border-color: yellowGreen;
}

.infinite-dood {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

.reset-button {
  color: indianRed;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid indianRed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.reset-button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: indianRed;
  border-color: darkRed;
}

.reset-dood {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <button class="infinite-button">
    <p class="infinite-dood">
      &#8734;
    </p>
  </button>
  <button class="reset-button">
    <p class="reset-dood">
      X
    </p>
  </button>
</div>
```

Something like this should do the trick